# How to close an active presentation that is open in MS PowerPoint in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

We have designed Microsoft Addins for MS PowerPoint 2019 written in VB.net. There we have taken a counter (pptCounter) which increases whenever a presentation (either existing or new) opens. So we want to delete this open presentation after the counter becomes more than 1.But it didn't close the open file.

We have used this below given snippet :

```
Private Sub WorkWithDocument(ByVal Doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation) Handles Application.PresentationOpen

 If (pptCounter > 1) Then

*Globals.Connect.Application.ActivePresentation.Close()*

End If

End Sub
```

Here is some more information about which environment I'm working in:

**Operating System** : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

**Code Editor** : Visual Studio 2019

**Technology** : Vb.net(.Net Framework 4.8)

**MS Office Version** : 2019(32 bit) : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 0):

The instance of the PowerPoint presentation is passed as a parameter to the method, so you need to use that object in the code instead of getting the active one:

```
Private Sub WorkWithDocument(ByVal Doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation) Handles Application.PresentationOpen

  If (pptCounter > 1) Then
    Doc.Close()
  End If

End Sub
```

In some cases it is not correct to close presentations in the `Open` event handler. So, I'd recommend letting the event handler finish its work and then close the just opened presentation right after the event handler is done. You can use a timer in VBA for scheduling a delayed action.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the right thing to close the open document within the same handler: *Application.PresentationOpen* because it is possible that some processing is still going on the handler so **add some additional handler** which executes after opening the presentation.

E.g. Like you have shared following method

```
Private Sub WorkWithDocument(ByVal Doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation) Handles Application.PresentationOpen
```

Which must be having handler in the start-up `AddHandler Application.NewPresentation, AddressOf WorkWithDocument`

Now do one thing add additional handler `AddHandler Application.NewPresentation, AddressOf AfterPresentationOpen` and call below method to close the presentation.
**For reference:**

```
Private Sub AfterPresentationOpen(ByVal Doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation) Handles Application.AfterPresentationOpen
  If (pptCounter > 1) Then
      Doc.Close()
  End If
End Sub
```

It will be surely called after opening the presentation so there is a high possibility close the presentation.